# systemverilog randomize() : Using subsection of a bitvector member

Tags: logic, constraints, system-verilog

I have an item:

```
class my_item extends uvm_sequence_item;                                  
  rand logic [31:0]           addr;
  ...
endclass
```

Somewhere in my seq, I want to constrain a portion of the `addr`:

```
  my_item temp_item;
  temp_item = my_item::type_id::create("temp_my_item");

  int mem_end_addr = 0x1234_5678;
  temp_item.randomize() with {
    ...
    addr[15:8] > mem_end_addr[15:8];  //---->>> does this work?
    ...
  };
```

Would SV `randomize()` with be able to deal with this kind of sub-selection of the `rand logic` field?

Answer (score 0):

SystemVerilog does not care which bits are constrained, just that the constraint expression must be true. That's why you should always call `randomize()` as part of a conditional statement that tests the return value.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that should work. Since you have constraints only on bits [15:8],  those bits would be generated accordingly while other bits would be random as it can.